# Service Browser for AMF calls (Flex to Java)

Tags: java, apache-flex, amf

Has anyone used or is aware of a service browser to test AMF calls?  I am looking for a tool similar to ZamfBrowser ( http://www.zamfbrowser.org ), but one that works for the Java environment. ZamfBrowser is geared towards AMFPHP.

The idea here is to provide a service browser, that allows developers to test Java services using the AMF protocol, without having to go through the Flex UI all the time. There has got to be something out there already for this, but I can't seem to locate anything..... It's kind of funny and strange that a service browser exists for AMFPHP but not for regular AMF calls in a Java environment.

I would imagine something exists under Blaze or LCDS? ... Trying to find it in the docs but can't seem to find anything ....

The best alternative I can think of at the moment is to use FlexMonkey to record stuff, and then to simulate it using that....which is okay I guess but still sucks because you have to go in and create the Flex UI first, whereas with something like ZamfBrowser, you simply point it at the service calls, it tells the server-side developers if their code works, etc. generates the required as3 classes for you... and makes the integration process much easier in a large team.

Any help or insight would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is quick and simple [Pinta](https://github.com/dunamis/pinta) tool for testing AMF services (any programming language). It is not so powerful as SoapUI but it is 100 times smaller in size :) Installed both of them on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are seeking [BlazeMonster](http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/blazemonster/)

Comment: Hey Joel

Thanks, will check out BlazeMonster. I used it a few months ago just for generating simple VOs, and maybe the v2 is diff, but I would think soapUI is much more comprehensive, but will have to check it out nevertheless. 

Much appreciated,

Tehsin

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so maybe all it took was a few more minutes of Googling. I found SoapUI http://www.soapui.org/tutorials/amf/amf-tutorial.html, which seems to be the tool for the job.  The name obviously doesn't sound like it would have anything to do with testing AMF calls, but ye it seems to do the job, also supports JMS...

I'd still be interested in any other tools available, especially if they have the capability of doing more sophisticated scenarios for the AMF calls.

Thanks,

Tehsin Bhayani