# How to enable amf sampler type

Tags: apache-flex, jmeter, load-testing, amf

I want to record script using amf proxy server but in http sampler setting amf type is missing. How should i enable amf type in amf proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first existent solutions:

**1.** [AMF Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf)
This will add the following new components:

- AMF Request
- AMF Request Defaults
- AMF Proxy Server

that will allow you to test your app using the AMF3 protocol:

> - Record AMF and HTTP traffic with the AMF Proxy Server
> - Translate AMF to XML for easy manipulation
> - Use variables to provide each virtual user with unique Client and Session IDs
> - Store response XML in a variable for assertion and value extraction
> - Review AMF responses as XML

NOTE: [not supported in JMeter 2.6](https://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf/issues/23), works with JMeter 2.5.1.

...And these two as possible addition:

**2.** [jmeter-amf-visualizer](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-amf-visualizer/)
JMeter visualizer AMF response.

**3.** [jmeter-amfsampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-amfsampler/)
JMeter sampler for testing Flex/BlazeDS applications using Adobe's AMF protocol over HTTP.

**4.** [UbikLoadPack Flex/AMF plugin](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/)
Commercial plugin from [UBIK Load Pack](https://ubikloadpack.com/).

Comment: Thank you Alies i already add this but still i am unable to record the script. When i put user id and password i get message your session has been expired and application logged out automatically. Why jmeter not logged in into the flex/flash application. Please suggest.

Comment: Application used tcp and http protocol. Does this work on jmeter.

Comment: @ pawanr. If you failed with recording script via jmeter proxywhy not to try record all the request-response chain using any traffic analyzer ([HTTP Analyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), etc.)

Comment: - and then to script recorded interaction using jmeter samplers?

HTTP Analyzer has, btw, native support for Flash Remoting (AMF0 and AMF3), as well as [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/AMF/getting-started.html) supports AMF protocol.
You could look also into [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954091/service-browser-for-amf-calls-flex-to-java).

...I have nothing to suggest in your situation, but if you are sitting and waiting after the first failure that somebody will solve your problem - here is not the best place for that.

Answer (score 1):

Apache JMeter does not propose AMF Sampler due to License incompatibility of BlazeDS with Apache licence.

Regarding your login issue you should check that you add a CookieManager to your test plan.
Then check you add the Java beans used by your Flex Application to send objects to Flex layer.

You can have a look at:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/
- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-flex-amf-plugin-4-0-for-apache-jmeter-released/
- [Performance testing Flex applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429841/performance-testing-flex-applications)